# How to create a Jar-Library of reusable sources with gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I'm developing right now on Project-A and I recognized, that outsourcing some parts would make sence since this stuff is reusable. I'm now thinking about creating a new project with gradle (Project-B), place all these reuseable sources in there and than include them as a dependency in Project-A again.

I have very rudimentary knowledge about gradle-build-files, so my question is, what are the basic steps in a build.gradle file to realise this?

Comment: Generate a jar from project B and publish it in a Maven repository. Producing a jar is the default in gradle, and there is a publishing plugin (even two actually) to publish your artefacts to a repo. Consume B from A as you would consume any other library from a Maven repository.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best option is to publish your Project-B as library to a local maven repository (which is just a directory in your filesystem). Of course you could also publish to a public repository if that's desired at some point.

Assuming you create such a local repository at `/path/to/repo` you can do as follows.

## For Project-B

In your `gradle.properties` define some variables:

```
pName=your-project-name
pGroup=your-group-name
pVersion=1.0.0
```

In your `settings.gradle`, set the project name:

```
rootProject.name = pName
```

In your `build.gradle`, apply the maven plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
```

Set these variables from the other file:

```
group = pGroup
version = pVersion
```

Also, define an upload task:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: file://localhost/path/to/repo)
        }
    }
}
```

You can then upload your project to the repository using

```
gradle clean uploadArchives
```

## For Project-A

Add your local repository to the list of maven repositories:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url /path/to/repo
    }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Then add a dependency on your Project-B:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'your-group-name:your-project-name:1.0.0'
}
```

That's it, Project-A should automatically pull the Project-B's jar file when running tasks such as `gradle build` or `gradle eclipse`

## Optionally publish sources

If you want the sources of Project-B included in the maven repositories so that your IDE can display the source code of your library, add this to your `build.gradle`:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}
```